# Using Software serial on ESP8266 with Lua

Tags: lua, at-command, esp8266, nodemcu, hm-10

I need to use ESP8266 standalone. I want to connect HM-10 bluetooth module to it and fire its AT commands and read the UUID of devices nearby.

I can do that by firing AT commands on HM-10 from Arduino and FT232RL. But how do I do it in Lua?

Comment: Not sure I understand...you want to connect an HM-10 to an ESP8266, then read data _from_ HM-10 using NodeMCU / Lua?

Comment: Thats right. And then send it using MQTT. The sending part is done.

Comment: Need to fire the AT command of HM-10, not ESP

Comment: Wire the HM-10 to Rx/TX and then read data using the UART module: http://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/uart/.

Comment: @MarcelStör thanks! It was very easy. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I didn't fully understand what the problem is. So, I was reluctant to give an answer based on vague ideas and assumptions. So, it seems you have an Arduino BT from which you send data to an HM-10 which is connected to the ESP8266. What the FT232RL's role is I still don't understand but it doesn't seem relevant in the context of the question.

Wire/solder the [HM-10](http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/SERIAL_PORT_BLE_MODULE_(MASTER/SLAVE):_HM-10) pins 1 & 2 to the ESP8266 RX/TX. Then you can read data using the NodeMCU UART module: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.org/en/dev/en/modules/uart. `uart.on()` allows to register callbacks triggered when data is received.

In case your ESP device is a NodeMCU devkit you might have to use `uart.alt()` depending on which RX/TX pins the HM-10 is connected to. The devkit has more than one set of RX/TX pins, see https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/.

Comment: I'm using the HM-10 to scan for iBeacons. I was able to fire the AT commands from Arduino and FT232RL, but didnt know how to do it from Lua. Thanks! :)